# The MediaPlayer in Android is not working

Tags: android

I m a beginner to Android development . I used the MediaPlayer class of android to play a file .But it shoots with an error of Mediaplayer error(-19,0)

```
package com.example.sound_play;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Sound extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sound);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(Sound.this, R.raw.n); 
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sound, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and the error i get is :

01-18 15:39:36.233: E/MediaPlayer(601): error (-19, 0)

Comment: what type of file you are trying?

Comment: I m using an .mp3 file of size 360kb, bitrate 101kbps , length = 0:28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not releasing the player after playing, add this-

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
{
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
    {
        mp.release();

    };
});
```

Hope, this will help you.